# How to output HTML tags to copy to elsewhere using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xmp

I have made a code that outputs data as html tags using document.write and the xmp HTML tag.
However, I have come across a problem. I have tried executing html, style, head and other tags but they do not work. Basic tags such as div, img, etc. seem to work fine. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Plz post some code dat u tried

Comment: You are correct, this is my mistake. I made a stupid coding mistake. It is fine now. If there are any other ways of doing this without xmp please let me know as it seems nobody seems to like xmp.

Comment: well u need to post some code for people to understand things better. Anywaz u solved the issue.Cheers to dat